# Angular - Set default option in Select

Tags: angular

i'm working on angular app, and i can't set the default option in a select, so how can i set a selected option in this select tag?

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="input.esquemas" name="esquemas" id="esquemas" class="form-control">                 
   <option value="AZBASWIT">Esquema 1</option>
   <option value="AZBASWDSMX">Esquema 2</option>
   <option value="AZBASWTPR">Esquema 3</option>
 </select>
```

I'm just starting with angular, so please bear with me, thanks.

Comment: The model is the single point of truth. You said Angular that the value of this select is the value of `input.esquemas`. So if you want AZBASWIT to be the selected option, input.esquamas must have the value "AZBASWIT".

Comment: yep, that was it, i set the value in the constructor and that did the trick, thanks man

Comment: before down voting clarify what is wrong in this question. Thanks. feedback will help user to improve further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set default option as "Select Value" something then use below :

```html
<select  [(ngModel)]="input.esquemas" name="esquemas" id="esquemas" class="form-control">         
<option [ngValue]="null">Choose Option</option>        
<option value="AZBASWIT">Esquema 1</option>
<option value="AZBASWDSMX">Esquema 2</option>
<option value="AZBASWTPR">Esquema 3</option>
</select>
```

Then if you used only three option then use this :

Any of value from three then set value for ngModel to respective value. Same as that.

Example :

```js
//in component
this.input.esquesmas = 'AZBASWDSMX';
```

```html
 <select  [(ngModel)]="input.esquemas" name="esquemas" id="esquemas" class="form-control">                 
                <option value="AZBASWIT">Esquema 1</option>
                <option value="AZBASWDSMX">Esquema 2</option>
                <option value="AZBASWTPR">Esquema 3</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: that's exactly what JB Nizet suggested, and it worked, thanks man